# Thread safe swapping in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a method which receives two bank account as inputs and swap their values :

```
Public void TransferAccount(AccountID  id1, AccountID id2){
    Account a1 = id1.GetAccount();
    Account a2 = id2.GetAccount();

    //Swap amounts.

    Temp = a1.Balance;
    a1.Balance = a2.Balance;
    a2.Balance = Temp;
}
```

I want to make this method to be thread-safe with the highest possible performance (I guess it means we may not make the method synchronized) , we have also to be careful about the deadlock ,

I thought of the following solution :

```
Public void TransferAccount(AccountID  id1, AccountID id2){
    Account a1 = id1.GetAccount();
    Account a2 = id2.GetAccount();

//Swap amounts.
    synchronized(a1){
        wait(a2);
        synchronized(a2){
            Temp = a1.Balance;
            a1.Balance = a2.Balance;
            a2.Balance = Temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any better implementation in terms of performance ? and by the way , is this thread-safe at all ?

Comment: *I guess it means we may not make the method synchronized* ... I guess this means  this is homework?

Comment: Wrong guess , next guess please
http://www.careercup.com/question?id=15903683

Comment: @BrianRoach: I don't see what makes you think that. The OP is saying "I need the highest possible performance, which I guess means I can't just make the method `synchronized`". That doesn't scream "homework" to me, though it does scream "lack of specific performance requirements".

Comment: "this method to be thread-safe with the highest possible performance"  If you did, one thread will be *much* faster than using multiple threads. i.e. more than 10x faster. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/why-concurency-examples-are-confusing.html See the `Accounting example`.

Comment: Even if it were, why is homework hated so much on SO?  I've never understood this.  I was once baffled by my homework.

Comment: @LaceCard it's hated because there is a high correlation between homework questions and 'do my work for me' questions, and while the S.O. community is really quite good, many of it's members really hate the latter sort of question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is subject to deadlock. If a thread calls `swap(a2, a1)` while another thread calls `swap(a1, a2)`, you'll have a deadlock.

You must make sure that you always lock your accounts in the same order. For example, assuming all the accounts are identified by a unique ID,

```
public void swap(Account a1, Account a2) {
    Account first = a1;
    Account second = a2;

    if (a1.getId().compareTo(a2.getId()) > 0) {
        first = a2;
        second = a1;
    }

    synchronized (first) {
        synchronized (second) {
            // swap the balances
        }
    }
}
```

Another big problem is that you access the balance of an account using a public field. Public fields should almost never be used, and especially not when an object is accessed by multiple threads. Use accessor methods, and make sure they're properly synchronized, or another thread won't see the new balances after the swap. Every shared state must always be accessed in a synchronized way.

But the first thing to do with your code is to make it compile, and respect the Java naming conventions.

Comment: Is there any way to do this only with wait , notify and synchronized and without considering ordering ?

Comment: I don't see how wait and notify are relevant to the problem. There's no reason to wait, and no reason to notify another thread.

Comment: Well, one can wait until another is finished and continue after it , from this perspective isn't possible to use wait and notify ?

Comment: That's what synchronized does: it blocks until the monitor is released. No need to wait for that.